# Convert an excel table from one structure to another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Team,

Besides macros, is there a formula or option based way to convert an excel sheet from one structure to another? I've used Alteryx but I'm brainstorming/interested in a simpler way using formulae to accomplish this.

Source format

```
ColA ColB    ColC
1    Apple   A1
2    Banana  B1
3    Kiwi    A1
4    Orange  C1
5    Peach   A1, C1
```

Target format

```
ColC  ColA                ColB
A1    Apple, Kiwi, Peach  1,3,5
B1    Banana              2
C1    Orange, Peach       4,5
```

Comment: It should be possible when you got access to the `TEXTJOIN` function.

Comment: Since both tables contain cells with multiple entities, any formula based approach will get very complex.  And for the same reason I don't think Pivot Tables will work for you.   I'd either rethink the whole design (if you have that option) or stick to VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using formula would not be a 'simpler' way but you can do so easily using **Power Query**, which is available in **Excel 2010 and later versions**. I will demonstrate my solution using Excel 2016.

There are multiple ways of adding your source data to the **Power Query Editor**, I prefer to turn it into a **Table** if it is not one already, and use **From Table** function to add it to the editor.

Once added, the editor will automatically set the format of **ColA** to **Number** and the other two to **Text**. It is important to manually change the format of ColA to **Text** as well.

[image: Formatting]

The next step is to split **ColC** using the built-in function **Split Column** (by Delimiter which is `Comma` in your case). It is important to **select `Rows` in the Advanced options**.

[image: Split Column]

Then you can **Trim** ColC to make it look neat and nice:

[image: Trim]

The next step is to use **Group By** function to group ColA and ColB by ColC. This step involves a manual coding as the built-in Group By function does not offer the option to combine texts in ColA and ColB so we need to manually change the original formula to make it happen. See below screen-shot for clarifications.

[image: Group By]

The correct formula is:

```
= Table.Group(#"Trimmed Text", {"ColC"}, {{"ColA", each Text.Combine([ColA],", "), type text}, {"ColB", each Text.Combine([ColB],", "), type text}})
```

Then you can **reorder the columns** by moving ColA to the end of the table.

[image: Re-order Columns]

Lastly, you can **Close & Load** the query to a new worksheet or to the same sheet with the source data as shown below:

[image: Outcome]

Let me know if you have any questions. Please see below full code behind the scene for reference only. Cheers :)

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ColA", Int64.Type}, {"ColB", type text}, {"ColC", type text}}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type",{{"ColA", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type2", {{"ColC", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "ColC"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"ColC", type text}}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"ColC", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Trimmed Text", {"ColC"}, {{"ColA", each Text.Combine([ColA],", "), type text}, {"ColB", each Text.Combine([ColB],", "), type text}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"ColC", "ColB", "ColA"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```